# PHP: Timezone adjustment function calculates Y-m-d H:i:s differently than Y-m-d

Tags: php, datetime

I have a custom-written PHP function which turns the passed passed value to the user's timezone (the `getSystem('timezone')` line).  Here is the function:

```
function dateAdjusted($format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $when = null) {

    if(is_int($when)) $when = date($format, $when); // already in epoch, change to string
    else $when = date($format, strtotime($when));
    $utc_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $when, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $local_date = $utc_date;

    $zone = getSystem('timezone');
    $zone_obj = new DateTimeZone($zone);
    $local_date->setTimeZone($zone_obj);

    $result = $local_date->format($format);
    return $result;
}
```

Notice that it always translates from UTC, since that's what we store in the database.  On a system where the timezone is set to `America/New_York` I get a weird bug:

`echo dateAdjusted('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2015-07-28 00:00:00')); // 2015-07-27 20:00:00`
`echo dateAdjusted('Y-m-d', strtotime('2015-07-28 00:00:00')); // 2015-07-28`

All I did is remove the `H:i:s` and it stops calculating over the day... what am I missing?

Comment: where do you define this "getSystem" function? Maybe the function try "date_default_timezone_get" to get the user timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$when = date($format, strtotime($when) is converting the datetime to the format you have defined.

Therefore $when will be missing the time of the date when you tried to convert the timezone.

Comment: Oh man... I must be tired, no clue how I missed that.  Thank you!